# adding icon to bundle using javapackager

Tags: java, windows, windows-installer, exe, javapackager

i am using javapackager to create an exe installer with jre bundled using the command line.

does anybody know how to add an icon and customise the installer using the command line.

these are the commands that i use:

```
javapackager -deploy -native -outdir packages -outfile myFile 
-srcdir documents -srcfiles Application.jar -appclass application.Main 
-name "Application" -title "Application Title"
```

i have tried to add license="info" and some other commands

Answer (score 9):

As [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javapackager.html#sthref235), use the option `icon` with the prefix `-B` to use a custom icon:

```
-Bicon=app.ico
```

or alternatively put the icon file at `package/windows/appName.ico`.

---

Here is a complete example for generating an EXE setup file:

**PREREQUISITES:**

- This will work on Windows only.
- You need to install Inno Setup 5 or newer from http://www.jrsoftware.org and add it to the PATH.

**COMMAND:**

> javapackager -deploy -native exe -Bruntime="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre" -Bicon=app_icon.ico -BsystemWide=true -BshortcutHint=true -outdir packages -outfile appFile -srcdir dist -srcfiles MyApp.jar;COPYING.txt -appclass somePackage.MainClass -BlicenseFile=COPYING.txt -name appName -title "The application name"

- **javapackager:** this is the Java packager tool, which is located at `%JDK_HOME%\bin\javapackager.exe`.
- **-deploy -native exe** : Generates a Windows .exe installer.
- **-Bruntime**: Location of the JRE to include in the package bundle.
- **-Bicon**: Path of the .ico file to be used as installer file icon.
- **-BsystemWide**: Flag that indicates if the application is installed in Program Files or in the standard location in the users home directory. Set to true to install the application in Program Files. Set to false to install the application in the user's home directory. The default is false.
- **-BshortcutHint**: Flag that indicates if a shortcut is placed on the desktop. Set to true to add a shortcut to the desktop. The default is false.
- **-BlicenseFile**: Text file that contains the license agreement which will be shown after starting the installation. This file should be inside `srcdir` and listed within `srcfiles`.

  - Note that `MyApp.jar` and `COPYING.txt` in this example are located at `./dist/` folder (as specified with -srcdir). `MyApp.jar` is an executable jar file.

**EXTRA:**

- You can customize the logo of the installer dialog by adding the following file ([max-size = 55x58 pixels](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_wizardsmallimagefile)):

```
package/windows/appName-setup-icon.bmp
```

- The following files are detected as well:

```
package/windows/appName.iss (Inno Setup project file)
package/windows/appName-post-image.wsf (script to run after application image is populated)
```

- Use the verbose option `-v` to see more details while `javapackager` is executed. After `javapackager` completes, it will print a message like this:

> Config files are saved to C:\Users\Fouad\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler3314360063389283581\windows. Use them to customize package.

You will find the following useful files in that folder:

- appName.ico
- appName.iss
- appName-setup-icon.bmp

---

For more:

- [The Java Packager Tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/packager.html).
- [javapackager (Windows) documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javapackager.html).

Comment: Thanks I am now getting the hang of it.                                                  To change the installer logo, where do I add the file:                              package/windows/appName-setup-icon.bmp                                            I have created a logo 55*55 in bmp format

Comment: is the package where the jar file is located?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\bin\javapackager -deploy -title Experiment -native exe -name Experiment -outdir build\dist -outfile Experiment -srcdir build\libs -appclass helloworld.HelloWorld -Bicon=C:\Projects\Copia\src\main\deploy\package\windows\Experiment.ico
 builds the installer (inno) but jsut uses the standard java icon.

Comment: To clarrify my previous comment, the icon is used for the .exe but not by windows in  the task bar or window frame.

Comment: Why do you need to install Inno setup? This is very surprising.

Comment: Oh, I found it in [Oracle 8 docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html), you need Inno Setup, to generate EXE package.